# Jave, Lucene : Search with numbers as String not working

Tags: java, lucene

I am working on integrating Lucene in our Spring-MVC based project and currently it's working good, other than search with numbers.

Whenever I try search like `123Ab` or `123` or anything which has numbers inside it, I don't get back any search results.

As soon as I remove the numbers though, it works fine.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Code :

```
 public List<Integer> searchLucene(String text, long groupId, boolean type) {
        List<Integer> objectIds = new ArrayList<>();
        if (text != null) {
            //String specialChars = "+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : \\ /";
            text = text.replace("+", "\\+");
            text = text.replace("-", "\\-");
            text = text.replace("&&", "\\&&");
            text = text.replace("||", "\\||");
            text = text.replace("!", "\\!");
            text = text.replace("(", "\\(");
            text = text.replace(")", "\\)");
            text = text.replace("{", "\\}");
            text = text.replace("{", "\\}");
            text = text.replace("[", "\\[");
            text = text.replace("^", "\\^");
            //  text = text.replace("\"","\\\"");
            text = text.replace("~", "\\~");
            text = text.replace("*", "\\*");
            text = text.replace("?", "\\?");
            text = text.replace(":", "\\:");
            //text = text.replace("\\","\\\\");
            text = text.replace("/", "\\/");
            try {
                Path path;
             //Set system path code
                    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
                    IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
                    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
                    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("contents", new SimpleAnalyzer());
                    Query query;
                    query = queryParser.parse(text+"*");
                    TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 50);
                    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
                        org.apache.lucene.document.Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
                        objectIds.add(Integer.valueOf(document.get("id")));
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("id " + document.get("id"));
                        System.out.println("content " + document.get("contents"));
                    }
                    indexSearcher.getIndexReader().close();
                    directory.close();
                return objectIds;
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
           }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Indexing code :

```
@Override
    public void saveIndexes(String text, String tagFileName, String filePath, long groupId, boolean type, int objectId) {
        try {
            //indexing directory
            File testDir;
            Path path1;
            Directory index_dir;
            if (type) {
            // System path code
            Directory directory = org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(path);
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);


            org.apache.lucene.document.Document doc = new org.apache.lucene.document.Document();
            if (filePath != null) {
                File file = new File(filePath); // current directory
                doc.add(new TextField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
            }
            doc.add(new StringField("id", String.valueOf(objectId), Field.Store.YES));
            //  doc.add(new TextField("id",String.valueOf(objectId),Field.Store.YES));
            if (text == null) {
                if (filePath != null) {
                    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuffer.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    stringBuffer.append("\n").append(tagFileName);
                    reader.close();
                    doc.add(new TextField("contents", stringBuffer.toString(), Field.Store.YES));
                }
            } else {
                text = text + "\n" + tagFileName;
                doc.add(new TextField("contents", text, Field.Store.YES));
            }
            indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
            indexWriter.commit();
            indexWriter.flush();
            indexWriter.close();
            directory.close();


        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
```

I have tried with and without wildcard i.e `*`. Thank you.

Comment: Its not about searching code but indexing code. Can you show that ( the indexing part ) and which version of lucene?

Comment: @SabirKhan : You are right, my mistake. Added the indexing code in main post. Kindly have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @SabirKhan : Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is in your indexing code.

Your field `contents` is a `TextField`  and you are using a `SimpleAnalyzer` so if you see `SimpleAnalyzer` documentation, it says ,

> An Analyzer that filters LetterTokenizer with LowerCaseFilter

So that means for your field, if it is set to tokenized numbers will be removed.

Now look at , `TextField` code, here a `TextField` is always tokenized irrespective of it being `TYPE_STORED` or `TYPE_NOT_STORED`.

So if you wish to index letters and numbers, you need to use a `StringField` instead of a `TextField`.

`StringField` documentation,

> A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is
>   indexed as a single token. For example this might be used for a
>   'country' field or an 'id' field, or any field that you intend to use
>   for sorting or access through the field cache.

A `StringField` is never tokenized irrespective of it being  `TYPE_STORED` or `TYPE_NOT_STORED`

So after indexing, numbers are removed from `contents` field and is indexed without numbers so you don't find those patterns while searching.

Instead of `QueryParser` and doing complicated searches, first use a query like below to first verify your indexed Terms,

```
Query wildcardQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term("contents", searchString));
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(wildcardQuery, 20);
```

Also, to know if debugging to be focused on indexer side or searcher side , use [Luke Tool](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) to see if terms are created as per your need. If terms are there, you can focus on searcher code.

Comment: Just changed from TextField to StringField, now I don't get back results for text I am trying to search as well.

Comment: what text you indexed and what did you searched ( i.e. `text` parameter value ) and also which version of Lucene?

Comment: Yours root cause for numbers was that I mentioned in code. I suggest to first use directly `WildCardQuery` , `TermQuery` etc instead of query parser to verify indexed Terms.

Comment: Lucene 5.4.1. Text indexed was helloworld1234. Tried searching hello, world, 1234, no results. Changed it back to TextField, got results for hello and world, nothing for numbers.

Comment: Just tried the same thing, no results when I use StringField, but when I use TextField, atleast I can search with text, not numbers.

Comment: Also, you should verify if you are not getting any hits or not getting values for `contents`  field? If simply field value is empty, make sure you are using `Store.YES` option for third argument in constructor.What I mean to say if line `System.out.println("id " + document.get("id"));` prints id or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143855/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-sabir-khan).

Comment: Can you please come back to chat. Thanks.